# SQL to merge the two tables according to the date where it overlaps and Get the count

Tags: oracle, merge

Please Help me on this.
I have two tables below (PROD_TABLE, STAGING_TABLE) with 3 primary keys (Assignment_ID, Effective_Start_Date & Effective_END_Date).

**PROD_TABLE**

```
            Assignment ID   Effective_Start_Date    Effective_END_Date
record 1:   60001           1/1/2001                2/1/2020
record 2:   60001           2/2/2020                2/2/2021
record 3:   60001           2/3/2021                3/19/2021
record 4:   60001           3/20/2023               12/31/4712
```

**STAGING_TABLE**

```
            Assignment ID   Effective_Start_Date    Effective_END_Date
record 1:   60001           1/1/2001                2/2/2021
record 2:   60001           2/3/2021                3/19/2021
record 3:   60001           3/20/2023               12/31/4712
```

I want to make a query to merge the two tables according to the date where it overlaps (Effective_Start_Date, Effective_END_Date) and get the count of the records from PROD_TABLE.

I want to get an output like the below (**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:):
1/1/2001 - 2/2/2021 will have a **COUNT** of 2 because in the PROD_TABLE, 1/1/2001 -            2/1/2020 and 2/2/2020 - 2/2/2021 falls in the range of 1/1/2001 - 2/2/2021 from the STAGING_TABLE.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
Assignment ID   Effective_Start_Date    Effective_END_Date  **COUNT**
60001           1/1/2001                2/2/2021            **2**
60001           2/3/2021                3/19/2021           **1**
60001           3/20/2023               12/31/4712          **1**
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE PROD_TABLE(ASSIGNMENT_ID   NUMBER, EFFECTIVE_START_DATE DATE,  EFFECTIVE_END_DATE DATE);
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (60001,   TO_DATE('1/1/2001', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/1/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (60001,   TO_DATE('2/2/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/2/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (60001,   TO_DATE('2/3/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('3/19/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (60001,   TO_DATE('3/20/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('12/31/4712', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));

CREATE TABLE STAGING_TABLE(ASSIGNMENT_ID NUMBER, EFFECTIVE_START_DATE DATE, EFFECTIVE_END_DATE DATE);
INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE VALUES (60001,    TO_DATE('1/1/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/2/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE VALUES (60001,    TO_DATE('2/3/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('3/19/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE VALUES (60001,    TO_DATE('3/20/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('12/31/4712', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Comment: You seems to be asking a question about SQL. Why did you not include a tag to the database system that you are using?  Can you please add that tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired output is given by:

```
select 
  ASSIGNMENT_ID,    
  EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, 
  EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
  (select count(*) 
   FROM PROD_TABLE p
   WHERE s.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE BETWEEN p.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND p.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
      or s.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE BETWEEN p.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND p.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
     ) as Count
from STAGING_TABLE s
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zb1x0tF3)

But I do **NOT** think this is a correct solution in all cases. It just happens to give the correct answer in this case.

EDIT:

```
-- This query converted to a query without subquery
select 
  s.ASSIGNMENT_ID,  
  s.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,   
  s.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
  count(*) as Count
from STAGING_TABLE s
left join PROD_TABLE p ON s.ASSIGNMENT_ID = p.ASSIGNMENT_ID and (
    s.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE BETWEEN p.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND p.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
    or s.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE BETWEEN p.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND p.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE)
GROUP BY 
  s.ASSIGNMENT_ID,  
  s.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,   
  s.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/jhfoaHNt)

Comment: Hi @Luuk - thank you. Is there a way to do this without using subquery? just asking :)

Comment: What have you tried ?  (see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rewrite+subquery+join )

Comment: Using subquery like what you have shared is my first thinking. Base on some other forums, they say it can be done using oracle analytic function... But i have little knowledge in SQL that's why I'm posting my problem here :) if i can get feedback/answers from you Guys who is already a Guru in SQL world

Comment: I added the same query without subquery.

Comment: many thanks man. God bless you for helping others like me solved this sql query problem.

Answer (score 1):

Select from the staging table and use a correlated sub-query to count the number of overlapping rows with the production table:

```sql
SELECT s.*,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM   prod_table p
         WHERE  s.assignment_id = p.assignment_id
         AND    s.effective_start_date <= p.effective_end_date
         AND    p.effective_start_date <= s.effective_end_date ) AS cnt
FROM   staging_table s
```

or, from Oracle 12, using a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT s.*,
       p.cnt
FROM   staging_table s
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
         FROM   prod_table p
         WHERE  s.assignment_id = p.assignment_id
         AND    s.effective_start_date <= p.effective_end_date
         AND    p.effective_start_date <= s.effective_end_date
       ) p
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

| ASSIGNMENT_ID | EFFECTIVE_START_DATE | EFFECTIVE_END_DATE | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60001 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 60001 | 2021-02-03 00:00:00 | 2021-03-19 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 60001 | 2023-03-20 00:00:00 | 4712-12-31 00:00:00 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gDo4gPNU)

Comment: Hi @MTO - thank you as usual. Is there a way to do this without using subquery? just asking :)

Comment: @IMDUMB Updated with a `LATERAL` join.

Comment: many thanks man. God bless you for helping others like me solved this sql query problem.